# How do I make the Zeppelin paragraph title dynamic?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

When we use Spark SQL Interpreter and download the output data, the filename will have a prefix of the paragraph title. So I want to make the paragraph title dynamic to represent the parameters used in the report.

Is there a way to make the paragraph title dynamic?